# I want to Convert Double type Values to Exponential Values in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

For example, I am giving one example to this.

Want the Replacement of this C# Function in T-SQL

```
sqlReader.GetDouble(i).ToString("E16")
```

This will be an original value --> `1.5`

Want to convert in this format -- > `1.5000000000000000E+000`

Answer (score 0):

Using [`REPLICATE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383(v=sql.110).aspx) you can achieve the `E16` format in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @TestVale AS VARCHAR (5) = '1.5';
SELECT @TestVale + REPLICATE('0', 16 - DATALENGTH(SUBSTRING(@TestVale, CHARINDEX('.', @TestVale) + 1, LEN(@TestVale) - CHARINDEX('.', @TestVale)))) + 'E+000'
```

By Replicate you can replace the 16 zeros with the current decimal value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...you are hot coding the Exponential Value.But i want only one fractional value before the Dot. For Ex : If @TestValue = 15.5 Your Result will be like '15.5000000000000000E+000' but i want the result as '1.55000000000000000E+001'